# Handling the Window without partition on huge dataset

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataset like,

```py
col1, col2, col3, timestamp
8,XXXX,XXXX,time
12,XXXX,XXXX,time
15,XXXX,XXXX,time
18,XXXX,XXXX,time
```

(sort order is the time here)
I am trying to create a new column based on previous row. My approach is.

```py
w = Window.orderBy('timestamp')

df.select('*',when())
```

**when and otherwise logic here by referencing the lag for previous row**

The question here is how spark handles this??, As the dataset size is huge, 10billion+rows I just want to understand what happens to a window function without a partition. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do that, you get the following warning by spark:

> WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all
>   data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance
>   degradation.

I think they made it quite clear, this will not work for huge datasets